# Validates columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to validate 2 different columns named 'Header1' and 'Header2'. Both the columns must have numerical values only if not i.e. text, special character or so, the macro should paste the no. of that cell (Having error) in column 'B' of a different sheet called "Error_Sheet".

And for column 'Header1' the value of cell 'A2' should be present whole through the column. And for column 'Header2' the value of B2 should be present whole through the column.

Blank/s are fine in the column.

[image]

here is my code:-

```
Sub CellCheck()

    Dim Header(1 To 2) As String
    Header(1) = "Header1"
    Header(2) = "Header2"

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sMyString As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

    Set rCell = Range("A2:A)

    If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) = False And _
       IsError(rCell.Value) = False Then

        Sheets("error_sheet").Range("A" & Row).Value = "There are " & _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumeric(r) & " Rows with error in column" & _
        Header(i)

        On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

        Set rCell = Range("B2:B)

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: To qualify for an answer you should ask a question. To qualify your question for an answer here you should make an own effort. So, post the code you already have and ask a question with regard to it.

Comment: Please show us what you already tried and a screen of how you want your data (not very clear in your post).

Comment: Ya here is my code:-

Comment: rCell is not complete as a range e.g. Range("B2:B) is incorrect syntax. Correct syntax would be, for example, Range("B2:B4")

Comment: (a) You are missing several line continuation characters (`_` ) (b) You are missing `End If` statements (c) You are missing a label `ErrorHandle` (d) You have used a variable `row` that has never been assigned a value (e) You have used a variable `r` that has never been assigned a value (f) You have used a variable `i` that has never been assigned a value